# how can I convert this foreach loop to linq?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm very new to Linq. I want to convert these lines of code to linq lambda expression, If it makes sense how can I achieve?

```
foreach (var Type in Essay.Text)
{
     string text =
          $"{"here is result"}\n{method(Type)}";
     if (text.Length <= 20 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(method(Type)))
     {
          Essay.Total += text;
     }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use the name of `Type`, as it already exist in C#.  Your object should be named something else.

Comment: Imho you should start by replacing string concatenation `Essay.Total += text;` by a StringBuilder.

Comment: ok, thank you for your advices

Comment: @someone Hi. Would you like to accept one of the answers below?

Answer (score 2):

With help of [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/):

```
Essay.Total = string.Concat(
            Essay.Text.Select(Type => new {Type, text = $"{"here is result"}\n{method(Type)}"})
                .Where(@t => @t.text.Length <= 20 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(method(@t.Type)))
                .Select(@t => @t.text)
            );
```

Comment: You can replace the `string.Join` by a `string.Concat`

Comment: @KooKiz really, didn't know about such overload method

Comment: thank you for your response, when I wanna help resharper, It converts to linq but its not lambda expression, is there any way to convert it to lambda in resharper settings?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
foreach (var type in from type in Essay.Text 
         let text = $"{"here is result"}\n{method(Type)}"
         where text.Length <= 20 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(method(Type)) select type)
{
    Essay.Total += type;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few pointers:

- There is no reason to call *method* twice, just cache it by using *let*
- You can also check the length of the text before constructing the final string

This should do the job for you:

```
var texts = from type in essay.Text
            let methodResult = method(type)
            where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(methodResult)
            let text = $"here is result\n{methodResult}"
            where text.Length <= 20
            select text;

essay.Total += string.Concat(texts);
```